# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied- wile using Watchdog lib

Tags: python

I'm trying to monitor a folder using the watchdog library. The problem is that sometimes the folder path monitoring works fine and sometimes I get an access error. What can I do in this case. I'll just add that running Visual code studio as an admin didn't help. Help!

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_to_monitor = r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject114"

    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=folder_to_monitor, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

I'll just add that running Visual code studio as an admin didn't help

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback.